# What does the is_sparse argument of input_variable really mean?

Tags: python, cntk

I thought is_sparse meant that the data to-be-bound to the variable would be in sparse format, but I am staring to think it means that the internal representation of the variable, after it is bound to data, is sparse.

In particular, I found this sample (in the source for one_hot).  Seems to work no matter if is_sparse is True or False.  And, I can't seem to bind the sparse_indicies directly to the i0 input_variable:

```
import cntk as C
import numpy as np

num_classes = 10
sparse_indices = [[5, 1, 3], [2], [5, 1, 6]]
i0 = C.input_variable(shape=num_classes, is_sparse=True)
z = C.times(i0, np.eye(num_classes))
value = C.one_hot(sparse_indices, num_classes)
z.eval({i0: value})
```

Answer (score 0):

When you perform:

```
z = C.times(i0, np.eye(num_classes))
```

`z` becomes a dense representation regardless of whether i0 is sparse or dense. Hence, the `is_sparse` flag does not have any consequence once `z` is formed.

Comment: If I create an input with "input_variable(100, is_sparse=True)", should I be able to bind sparse data to it (one-hot indexes vs. one-hot vectors)?